# SVN syncing fails with ZendStudio

Tags: svn, zend-studio, unfuddle

When I try to sync with my SVN (I'm using unfuddle) through ZendStudio I get the following error:

> Some of selected resources were not committed. svn: Commit failed
>   (details follow): svn: MKACTIVITY request failed on
>   '/svn/test1234_a/!svn/act/58ae0e6d-2301-0010-8300-cb465553b788' svn:
>   MKACTIVITY of
>   '/svn/test1234_a/!svn/act/58ae0e6d-2301-0010-8300-cb465553b788': 400
>   Bad Request (http://test1234.unfuddle.com)

I think this is some type of proxy error, but how can I fix this (using ZendStudio).

Thanks.

Comment: some more details, please: setup versions commands , etc..

Answer (score 0):

Zend Studio runs in Eclipse, doesn't it?

I had the same problem today with a regular Java project in Eclipse. A SVN clean helped: right-click on project -> Team -> cleanup.